# Symfony2 Formbuilder: How to change generated default name attribute of input tags

Tags: symfony, formbuilder

I want to replace by the formbuilder the default generated name of input tag

Comment: Could you please be more specific? Do you want your `<input>`s to have `name` attribute set to a non-default value? 
Please supply some code that would show what you're getting now and how you have implemented it, and what's the desired result.

Comment: motivation: Chorem 34 version ignored autocomplete='off' therefore, registration form autocompleted wrong <input> field (saved password)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the form name and override `property_path` option, eg:

```
$builder
    ->add('normal_field', 'text')
    ->add('overriden_path_field', 'text', ['property_path' => 'my_new_path'])
;
```

And submit:

```
array (size=2)
    'normal_field' => string 'Here' (length=4)
    'overriden_path_field' => string 'Here too!' (length=9)
```

And the result would be:

```
object(A)[2]
    public 'normal_field' => string 'Here' (length=4)
    public 'my_new_path' => string 'Here too!' (length=9)
```

Have in mind, if you are not binding form to objects, but to array you should change `property_path` from `my_new_path` to `[my_new_path]`, see the the [PropertyAccess Component Docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_access/introduction.html) for all possibilities.